# Error message on adding apple card in wallet

Tags: iphone, wallet

I have iPhone 7 Plus running on the latest 14.4 IOS. I am trying to add my Apple Card to my Wallet:

1. click on the **+** sign in wallet
2. enter my apple login credentials
3. click **Sign In**
4. as soon as it signs in the error pops up: (null)-(null)

The error has only **OK** button so when I click on it I am taken back to my Wallet which has the rest of my credit and debit cards. I don't have a problem adding another card, this only happens with the Apple Credit Card.
I called Apple Credit Card support and they assured me the account and credit card looked OK. They then transferred me apple iphone support which went with me through my phone settings, got some logs etc and passed the info to their software engineers. Haven't heard back yet. Has anybody experienced this issue?

[image: Error Message Adding Apple Card to Wallet]